# How to ignore some builds in Hudson test results trend?

Tags: testing, hudson, jenkins

Sometimes the hudson build step fails and does not execute all my tests, which really screws up the test trend graph because it shows a 50% drop in the number of tests and then goes up again. Is there a way to exclude the failed builds? I tried to delete the whole failed build but that didn't help.

Comment: Isn't the point of this graph not to look nice but to give an overview about when/how often builds *failed* ?

Comment: hehe well it's not about looking nice, but it's not about showing failed builds either (thats what the build status lamps and the weather icons are there for). It is really about the number of tests and the number of failing tests. If there's some problem with the ci environment, but not with the tests or the code, then the graph get's just wrong. It's not /true/ that the number of tests dropped from 200 to 100, they are still there and would even pass under normal circumstances... So it doesnt serve it's purpose of showing a "number of tests trend" anymore. And it's ugly ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you delete the "offending" build and then run another build I think you'll find the trend graph is rebuilt without the blip.

That said, I have to side with @DarkDust on this one. If your CI environment is prone to wobble then these stats can be useful for diagnostics.

Comment: Actually this causes the trend to be cleared and started from next build after deleted one.